# Getting content web page using requests

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I'm trying to get the content of a html web page by using

```
r = requests.get(url-page)

r.text()
```

I would like to get back the entire html page but unfortunately I got the following error

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.text` is just a property on the `Response` object.

**Example:**

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> response = get("http://www.google.com")
>>> response.text[:9]
u'<!doctype'
>>>
```

You don't have to "call" the attribute if it's a property just like any normal object attribute access.

See: requests' documentation on [Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Answer (score 1):

`r.text` without parens, not `r.text()`, `text` it is a property not a method

You are basically doing:

```
In [3]: s = u"hello"

In [4]: s()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8df90e2d9e86> in <module>()
----> 1 s()

TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```